# Interpolate sql in SQLDataset in catalog.yml

Tags: python, kedro

Is there a way to interpolate a SQLDataset query in `catalog.yml` passing some argument\parameter.
Example:

```yaml
person:
  type: pandas.SQLQueryDataSet
  sql: "SELECT * FROM public.people WHERE id = ${id};"
  credentials: db_credentials
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [answered on slack](https://kedro-org.slack.com/archives/C03RKP2LW64/p1678886253605289) you can use [TemplatedConfigLoader](https://docs.kedro.org/en/0.18.6/kedro_project_setup/configuration.html#template-configuration), but beware of SQL injection risks!

Comment: @ datajoely could you elaborate your answer, I cannot see older answers on slack (paid)

Comment: Hi @AHR - please find our slack archive here
https://linen-slack.kedro.org/t/10022566/hi-guys-quick-question-is-there-a-way-to-interpolate-a-sqlda#81b4bb9e-9083-4320-83d9-cf0fab247e9c